# Remote calls using sockjs or dnode as possible replacements for nowjs

Tags: javascript, node.js, sockjs, dnode

I am looking at alternatives for Nowjs, for making remote function calls from the client on a NODEJS server, and have stumbled upon dnode and sockjs as possible options. Can someone point out the difference and advantages of one over another, OR if i should be looking at some other module?